# Unfortunately Application has stopped after running it from Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="15dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

That is the customized layout xml file I am trying to create.

Here's my code for 
MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.nabil.listviewexample;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String [] TVShows = {"Breaking Bad", "Friends", "Sons of Anarchy", "Pushing Daisies",
                            "Life on Mars", "Walking Dead", "Game of Thrones"};

    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_layout ,TVShows);

    ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String tvShowPicked = "You Selected " + String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tvShowPicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is    present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
            }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

But every time I try to run in on my galaxy s4, it says Unfortunately Application has stopped. I am still new to this, and I hope it is not a big issue. Thanks!

Screen shots from my logcat:[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post your error stack trace.

Comment: I don't see any ListView in your XML layout. You probably have a `NullPointerException` when you call `listView1.setAdapter()` because it couldn't find a ListView, so your `listView1` is null.

Comment: Post your log cat error

Comment: Add a list view with the id listView1 in your layout.

Comment: Please post your error stack trace

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Post your logcat stack trace.

Comment: I will post pictures @サラマラージ

Comment: As @Karakuri pointed out, there is no ListView in your layout, only a TextView. You'll need to add a ListView.

Comment: Next time, please do not post screenshots of your logcat. Copying and pasting the logcat text and enclosing it in code tags is better for us. It's easier for us to read, it's easier for search engines to index, and it's easier for us to copy small snippets out of it and search for those snippets using a search engine (not that we needed to do that in this case, but sometimes we do need to).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I didn't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your XML-Layout file should be the layout of the rows of the list, then as your stacktrace tells you, you are having a LinearLayout where you should only have a TextView. The ArrayAdapter takes only a single TextView as layout as this is the place where it will show your content.

This should be your row_layout.xml:

```
<TextView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="15dp" />
```